# convert int to string for use in allegro function

Tags: c++, allegro

I am trying to run the following code using allegro.

textout_ex(screen, font, numbComments , 100, 100, GREEN, BLACK);

numbComments is an integer,
the function prototype of this function is

```
  void textout_ex(BITMAP *bmp, const FONT *f, const char *s, 
                                      int x, int y, int color, int bg);
```

and i cannot, according to my understanding pass this integer in the third position.

I therefore need to convert the integer into a char*s.

Help please?

i cannot, of course, change the actual function prototype

Comment: http://www.allegro.cc/manual/api/text-output/textout_ex - Writes a string on a bitmap.

Comment: I see the answer is the same, i still dont understand what to put where though, please can you copy the whole code that i pasted with the changes or explain more simply

Answer (score 2):

`Str` is a `std::string`. `textout_ex` requires a `const char*`. Use `Str.c_str()` to retrieve the C `const char*` data format from `Str`.

Answer (score 1):

`textout_ex` expects a `const char*`, and your `Str` is a `string`, try calling `textout_ex` with `Str.c_str();`

**Edit:**
Applied to your code : 
`textout_ex(screen, font, Str.c_str(), 100, 100, GREEN, BLACK);`

Comment: I see the answer is the same, i still dont understand what to put where though, please can you copy the whole code that i pasted with the changes or explain more simply

Comment: thanx, however, the function prototype is set, I did not make it and dont think I have access to it?

also, I wish to put characters into the function in other places within the code.

is there no way to just convert my integer to what is needed?

Answer (score 0):

Use `textprintf_ex` like:

`textprintf_ex(bmp, f, x, y, color, bg, "%d", numbComments);`

It works just like [printf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).